# How to fix sqlite3 libversion mismatch

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, ios8.2

I just updated to the latest Xcode, version 6.2 and started seeing this error when running my app.

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: sqlite3 libversion mismatch: headers report 3007013, but library reports 3008005

The error shows up running in the simulator using iOS 8.2, but works fine in iOS 8.1. My app includes libsqlite3.dylib from Apple.

Any suggestions on the cause or how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with MapboxGL and ios 8.2 as described here:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/968

This looks like the version check in question:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/b56b618abf0b15025b61ab96dcc873cf7af82450/platform/default/sqlite3.cpp

Comment: Well, that certainly does seem to be the cause. And thanks for creating an account to answer my question today.